# Javascript CSV to Excel autoround up Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, number-formatting

Below code is written to export data to csv file. It's working fine. But when open that csv using ms-excel some long numbers (Ex: 20000067538XXXXXX) are auto round up. Is there any way to fix this issue in JavaScript coding.

[image: Please Refer this Image]

Comment: post your code as text and not picture. learn how to ask [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The example shows the rounding at 11 significant digits. Both JavaScript and Excel round at about 15 to 16 digits. Are you incorrectly  showing the rounding?

Comment: See [Last digits are changed to zeroes when you type long numbers in cells of Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/269370/last-digits-are-changed-to-zeroes-when-you-type-long-numbers-in-cells).